# Is it possible to make a rest request to Flask within 1 millisecond?

Tags: python, flask

I am creating an application on Python3.6 with Flask and uwsgi. The logic is very simple, it is just return a `ok` in the response:

```
# main
import connexion

def main():
    app = connexion.App(__name__)
    app.add_api('openapi.yaml',
                arguments={'title': 'Service'})
    app.run(port=8080)

# endpoint
def health_get():
    return "OK"
```

as above code, it basically responses to health check. In the client side, I am using `request` library to send rest request:

```
s = requests.Session()
...

response = s.get('http://localhost:8080/health')

...
```

I measure the time spend on the request `s.get('http://localhost:8080/health')`. It takes about 3 milliseconds. Both server and client run in `localhost` which means there is no network latency.   I can't think about any improvement. It seems that the framework takes most of the time. Is it possible to improve the performance to be less than 1 millisecond?
And this is not a heavy load test case, a few requests per second is good enough.

If it is not possible, whether websockt connection is an option?

Comment: You mean 1 millisecond (ms). 1 million seconds is about 15 days haha.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is something you'd be able to improve with better syntax in python. Looking at a faster language like C++ or Java could help as they are compiled whereas python is interpreted, therefore making it slower.

If you are committed to python, your other option is increasing your bandwidth. This can be achieved by using ethernet.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with bandwidth! that too in a local ethernet unless you are using a network card 10 years old!!

Comment: I don't see another connection of which the speed could be increased. The one ping I do see is the one between your computer and the router. If that becomes wired, the bandwidth could increase and potentially give you your desired output. You could always try a compiled language.

Comment: What I meant was connection speed doesnt seem to be matter in this case

Answer (score 0):

I have a proposal for you, If you are designing just a heartbeat app and you want to stick with `python`. `connexion` and `requests` are not the right candidates for that. You can try [bjoern](https://github.com/jonashaag/bjoern) server and python's [http-client](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/http.client.html) together. This will reduce a lot of wrapper logic in the code. It will improve the performance for sure. I cannot predict the benchmark at this point.